# Celery beat not starting EOFError('Ran out of input')

Tags: python, celery, celerybeat, kombu

Everything worked perfectly fine until:

```
celery beat v3.1.18 (Cipater) is starting.
__    -    ... __   -        _
Configuration ->
    . broker -> amqp://user:**@staging-api.user-app.com:5672//
    . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
    . scheduler -> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
    . db -> /tmp/beat.db
    . logfile -> [stderr]@%INFO
    . maxinterval -> now (0s)
[2015-09-25 17:29:24,453: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
[2015-09-25 17:29:24,457: CRITICAL/MainProcess] beat raised exception <class 'EOFError'>: EOFError('Ran out of input',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/staging/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kombu/utils/__init__.py", line 320, in __get__
    return obj.__dict__[self.__name__]
KeyError: 'scheduler'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/shelve.py", line 111, in __getitem__
    value = self.cache[key]
KeyError: 'entries'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/staging/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/apps/beat.py", line 112, in start_scheduler
    beat.start()
  File "/home/user/staging/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 454, in start
    humanize_seconds(self.scheduler.max_interval))
  File "/home/user/staging/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kombu/utils/__init__.py", line 322, in __get__
    value = obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = self.__get(obj)
  File "/home/user/staging/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 494, in scheduler
    return self.get_scheduler()
  File "/home/user/staging/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 489, in get_scheduler
    lazy=lazy)
  File "/home/user/staging/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/utils/imports.py", line 53, in instantiate
    return symbol_by_name(name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/staging/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 358, in __init__
    Scheduler.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/staging/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 185, in __init__
    self.setup_schedule()
  File "/home/user/staging/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 377, in setup_schedule
    self._store['entries']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/shelve.py", line 114, in __getitem__
    value = Unpickler(f).load()
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

How can I solve the error?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I've deleted my `celerybeat-schedule` files and it solved my problem.

https://github.com/celery/kombu/issues/516

Comment: Thank you ! Saved my day . just in case someone wants the names of files : `celerybeat-schedule.bak` , `celerybeat-schedule.dir` , `celerybeat-schedule.bak` .

Comment: It worked for me as well, in my case I had a file called celerybeat-schedule without extension in my AWS EC2 instance. After removing it it stopped showing the error. Both celery worker and beat worked fine though even with the error showing.

Answer (score 1):

I could solve the same error by deleting all `celerybeat-schedule` files `celerybeat-schedule.bak`, `celerybeat-schedule.dat` and `celerybeat-schedule.dir` just under my Django project folder.

Comment: This appears to just repeat the solution by the OP.